# Using an array for indexing for training network (tensorflow)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor

I am relatively new to tensorflow and am running into problems trying to index tensors properly. Towards the bottom of the shown, I am trying to use x (which itself is a tensor containing an array form such as [[0,1], [2,3]]) in order to index the y_rt tensor (one can think it as slicing the y_rt tensor). However, I am having troubles converting the tensor into an array or list. I am aware that there is the .eval() function, however I cannot use it here since the shown code happens before the .run() call. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
with tf.name_scope('placeholders'):
x_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, size, size, 1], name="x_true")
y_rt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, operator.range.shape[0], operator.range.shape[1], 1], name="y_rt")
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, shape=(), name='is_training')
angle = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[n_batches, number], name="projection_order")
ordersel = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[n_batches, number], name='order_selection')
selection = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[number], name='iteration_selection')
dual = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, number, 183, 1], name='dual')
y_par = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, number, 183, 1], name='y_partial')

for i in range(n_batches): #iterations, the amount of projection batches we have
    with tf.variable_scope('my_iterate{}'.format(i)):

        value = layer_sub(primal[..., 1:2], epoch_angle[i])  
        x = (selection[i])
        y_partial = y_rt[:, selection, :, :] #y_rt is of form (?,total, 183, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 1.9 TensorFlow doesn't support indexing by arrays using slice notation. From the [tf.Tensor documentation for `__getitem__`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask):

> This operation extracts the specified region from the tensor. The notation is similar to NumPy with the restriction that currently only support basic indexing. That means that **using a non-scalar tensor as input is not currently allowed**.

If you want more advanced indexing than simple scalars, [`tf.boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) can help you select tensor elements using a boolean array and [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) can help you select elements using an integer array.

Note in your example, the index specified by `x` would be a scalar with your 1-d `selection` tensor, and would work for slice notation if you used it:

```
x = selection[i]
y_partial = y_rt[:, x, :, :]
```

but indexing into `selection` for each of your training batches probably isn't what you want here.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. Could you refer me to the documentation or example of how I can achieve the masking?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a link to the documentation for the tf.boolean_mask op. The examples there should be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. Regarding your answer, I wanted to quickly ask another question: Once the session starts running, does tensorflow convert tensors to arrays. Does this have something to do with def _impl (inside a function)?

Comment: The tf.Tensor object is TensorFlow's abstract representation of a multidimensional array. Before a session starts it's just an empty shell. Once the session starts running, the tensor is populated with actual values from the graph you define before starting the session. If you have not read it already, [the documentation provides a great explanation of graphs and sessions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs). I'm sorry I don't know what you mean about your def _impl question.